# Translating a teapot in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

Here is the last codes of my reshape func :

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluLookAt(0,0,-10,
                  0,0,0,
                  0,1,0);

}
```

And here is my display func :

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0,5,0);
glutSolidTeapot(2);
glPopMatrix();
```

Teapot's Top will be crashed , it seems rotated around x axis to backward ? why i get this ?
How can I just translate teapot without any crash ?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean "crashed"?

Comment: the head of the teapot will be removed...

Comment: can you put the image in the question?

Comment: looks pretty much how I'd expect.

Comment: I can't really tell without more code, but I think you need to change GL_MODELVIEW to GL_PROJECTION when modifying the view matrix (i.e. `gluLookAt(...)`, and make sure you're back in GL_MODELVIEW when adding your translate.

Comment: @rvalue lookat is a view matrix, not a projection matrix, so it doesn't belong in the GL_PROJECTION stack.

Comment: @JasonD True, I must've been doing too well at avoiding GLU recently. Does the teapot look as you'd expect if you comment out the `glTranslatef(...)` call, @Parkhid ?

Comment: @Parkhid What happens when you put a box on a shelf at eye level when standing and then move your eye level by sitting on the floor (which is equivalent to moving the box up by the same distance)? You see more of the bottom of the box and no longer see the top, right? That's what's happening with your teapot.

Comment: so i am viewing teapot from bottom ?? ooo

Comment: Yes, when you look at the origin and translate an object in the up direction (in this case the y direction) you're putting the object above eye level.

Comment: Add light (Normal shading) will reveal the unseen shape ...